# Mongodb aggregate update field in sub array

Tags: mongodb, updates, aws-documentdb

First of all, I'm using DocumentDB from AWS, so I've not all MongoDB functions.

I have these records:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609be32555c7753b0cb21fsd"),
    "validaProdutos" : [ 
        {
            "atributos" : [ 
                {
                    "codigo" : "seller",
                    "valores" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609be32555c7753b0cb20edc"),
    "validaProdutos" : [ 
        {
            "atributos" : [ 
                {
                    "codigo" : "brand",
                    "valores" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609be32555c7753b0cb32123"),
    "validaProdutos" : [ 
        {
            "atributos" : [ 
                {
                    "codigo" : "seller",
                    "valores" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

And I need to update validaProdutos.atributos.codigo to "done" when validaProdutos.atributos.codigo === "seller"

I've tried so many things, but the last try was:

```
db.col1.aggregate([
{ 
    "$addFields": { 
        "validaProdutos.atributos": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$validaProdutos.atributos",
                as: "item",
                cond: [{ $eq: ["$$item.codigo", "seller"] }, "done", "$$item.codigo"]
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "col1" } 
},
])
```

But it doesn't works, just get a list not modified.

Somebody helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `update` method with arrayFilters and multi equals true, to affect all documents in your collection:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ln2qMCm9GMB

```js
db.collection.update(
  {},
  {
    $set: {
      "validaProdutos.$[].atributos.$[a].codigo": "done",
    },
  },
  {
    multi: true,
    arrayFilters: [
      {
        "a.codigo": "seller",
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. 
You wrong. Aggregate with $addFields or $set and $out flag can write as well. I'm using aggregate because in this case, I can't using well update with AWS DocumentDB. 
Anyway, that has a given me an idea!

Comment: You're right. Since version 4.2, released last year, `set` can make changes in documents. I didn't know about that... I'll modify what I said in the answer... Thanks for advise me!